# Class fl.controls::CheckBox could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

I am loading external swf that contain checkbox on the stage.
but when I try to load that swf I get an error "Class fl.controls::CheckBox could not be found."

I build the application with pure as3 in flash builder 4 
and the external swf made by flash pro cs4

Thanks,

Comment: Does the swf you're loading work fine by itself?

Comment: the external swf dont throw this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fl.controls` namespace is a part of Flash Pro.

To integrate with Flash Builder, you can either add the package by SWC or via code:

Adding Flash Components to Flash Builder:

**Adding by SWC:**

- Right-click on your project in Flash Builder, and go to Properties.
- Select "ActionScript Build Path" from the left.
- Go to the "Libary path" tab now available on the right.
- Click "Add SWC..."
- Add libs from Flash such as flash.swc or IK, depending on what version of the Flash IDE you have and where you installed it.

*Windows:*
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\libs\flash.swc

*Mac OS X:*
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc

**Adding by source folder:**

- Right-click on your project in Flash Builder, and go to Properties.
- Select "ActionScript Build Path" from the left.
- Go to the "Source path" tab now available on the right.
- Click "Add Folder..."
  The Flash components should be in a location with a path similar to the following, depending on what version of the Flash IDE you have and where you installed it.

*Windows:*
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface

*Mac OS X:*
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Component Source/ActionScript 3.0/User Interface

Comment: nicely explained/documented +1

Comment: I did it and now I get TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at fl.controls::CheckBox/drawLayout()
 at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
 at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()

Comment: Now that the package resolves, perhaps you should post a new question with code and FLA authoring relevant to the checkbox.

Comment: didn't help. swc connected, but there is not controls package in it.

Comment: @DataGreed Use source folder instead.