# Insert a CheckBox in actionScript only without Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, checkbox, actionscript

Is it possible to insert a checkBox without using Flash, just plain ActionScript3? We are not being able to import the fl library that's why I am asking

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you mean using Flash CC you have to add the component in library first then you can import it in code and create new instances on the fly.

Comment: It's part of the fl library, so no.   You can make your own checkBox through code.  Or just import a swc that has the checkbox component in it - or just import flash.swc which has everything (though you still may need the display assets separately).   See this quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035052/class-fl-controlscheckbox-could-not-be-found

Comment: Create your own class. With the possibilities of the graphics-object and its drawing-methods, it is easy to create a simple checkbox. The logical part (checked-unchecked) is really simple.

Comment: I will make my own through code thank you very much for the info!